# Getting an error when trying to secure controller method with securesocial

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, securesocial

When trying to implement a SecuredAction like this:

```
def index = SecuredAction {
    Ok(views.html.index())
}
```

I'm getting a

```
Overloaded method value [SecuredAction] cannot be applied to (play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[play.api.templates.Html])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about `implicit request =>`

So:

```
def index = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
}
```

Is correct.